# Calendar DisplayDate incorrect in year view after being modified in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, calendar

I am working in WPF and C#. In using the Calendar control I encountered the following problem with it:

If I modify the DisplayDate in code behind, clicking the month header goes to year view but displays an incorrect date.

While doing some tests, I noticed that as soon as I press the month header, the DisplayDate is changed back to what it was prior to my code-behind changes.

Is there a way to change the DisplayDate in code behind and have it 'stick'?

Here is a quick code snippet to reproduce the problem:

```
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <Calendar x:Name="myCalendar" />
      <Button Content="Prev" Click="btnPrev_Click" />
      <Button Content="Next" Click="btnNext_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>

  private void btnPrev_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.ChangeDisplayDate(this.myCalendar.DisplayDate.AddMonths(-1));
  }

  private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.ChangeDisplayDate(this.myCalendar.DisplayDate.AddMonths(1));
  }

  private void ChangeDisplayDate(DateTime newDate)
  {
    // Method 1
    //this.myCalendar.DisplayDate = newDate;

    // Method 2
    this.myCalendar.ClearValue(Calendar.DisplayDateProperty);
    this.myCalendar.SetValue(Calendar.DisplayDateProperty, newDate);
  }
```

Both methods shown in ChangeDisplayDate() will change the DisplayDate, but won't prevent it from reverting back when clicking the month header.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set both [DisplayDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaydate(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SelectedDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx) properties:

```
myCalendar.DisplayDate = newDate;
myCalendar.SelectedDate = newDate;
```

in your code-behind.

Comment: But I don't want to change the SelectedDate, I only want to change which month is displayed in the Calendar. The same as when the user manually clicks on the right/left arrows to change the month. That action doesn't change the SelectedDate, only the DisplayedDate. In the end I want to do the equivalent of clicking those buttons but in code behind instead.

Comment: Clicking on next button does change `DisplayDate`. You can see it by adding `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayDate, ElementName=myCalendar}"/>` to XAML code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for `Calendar`, there doesn't appear to be a way to programmatically navigate to a different 'page', e.g., month view.  The date used internally for navigation seems to be `CurrentDate`, but that property is marked `internal`, and the navigation methods that manipulate it are also inaccessible.  It seems that `DisplayDate` only governs the *initial* page/date, i.e., determines the navigation starting point in cases where `SelectedDate` starts out as `null`.  After the calendar is displayed, changing that property has no effect.

This appears to be a very poorly designed control.  A design that embraced the WPF philosophy would use routed commands to navigate, in which case you could simply fire the appropriate command.  But this design seems to handle clicks from specific buttons in the template and keyboard gestures only.  You may be out of luck, I'm afraid.

If you really need to make this work so you can hit a milestone, you could always invoke the calendar's `MoveDisplayTo`, `OnNextClick`, or `OnPreviousClick` method using reflection, but I wouldn't recommend doing that for your release.  Better to live without the behavior or switch to a more flexible calendar control.